# interfacing tcs3200 color sensor with STM32f746zg

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, frequency-measurement, stm32cubemx, hal-library

I want to interface TCS3200 color sensor with STM32f746ZG. Since the TCS3200 outputs a frequency based on the amount of light received, I need some way to count the number of pulses for different colors to determine a color.

In CubeMX, I set PF6(s0) PF7(s1) PF8(s2) PF9(s3) and TIM2 ch1 input capture as (out) of the sensor. Frequency for timer 2, I selected to be 84MHz with prescalar 83 which will bring it to 1MHz (I am not sure whether I should do this or not). I also enabled TIM2 global interrupt in nvic window. Next, I activated TIM6 to measure time of 5s (timer f=84MHz, prescalar=41999 and counterperiod = 9999).

**I have doubt about how to use these two timers inside the while loop, which HAL library functions to use here and how to use.**

CubeMX is the source code generator and the IDE is Kiel5. Following is my setting for output frequency scaling and filter type outside the main function. If I am wrong, please correct me.

```
void TCSFREQ()

      {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s0_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
   }

void TCSRED()

      {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s3_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
   }

void TCSBLUE()

      {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s3_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
   }

void GREEN()

      {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s3_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
   }

void TCSCLEAR()

      {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF,  s3_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
   }
```

Correct me if there is something wrong above.

As I am new to microcontrollers, I am struggling with how to count the number of pulses in a time period (let's say 5s). It would be nice if you would help me with my problem or suggest some alternative solution.

How do I count the no of pulses from output of that sensor?

Comment: alternative solution https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/TCS3200_Color_Sensor_(SKU:SEN0101)

Comment: Timers in interrupt mode, work independently of the while loop! If your question is about how to configure timers to measure a pulse in input capture mode, you can start with some example libraries. ST provided several example libraries, for you [stm32f7cube](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef7.html) is relevant.

Comment: Please write a specific question so it's clear to others what question you want answered.

Comment: @laptop2d ..how to count no of pulses from output of that sensor?